# Force HTTPS in asp net core angular project

Tags: angular, heroku, .net-core, https

I created a .net core project with the angular template. I want to use only https (or atleast redirect all http to https), but I can't figure out how to redirect the angular application to https when the initial request was http. I am hosting through Heroku with docker.

Https can be used when i specify https:// before my domain name.

SSL is setup automatically by Heroku.

I even tried using an interceptor where I check the header specified in the Heroku documentation and change the window.location.href to https but one it does not work and two it looks like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have setup redirect and forwarded headers.

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => { options.HttpsPort = 443; })

services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

Full example here https://github.com/jincod/AspNetCoreDemoApp/blob/master/src/AspNetCoreDemoApp/Startup.cs